# Maximum recursion depth exceeded when inserting in BST

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a Binary Search Tree and I believe my logic for the insert method is perfectly fine but my code throws a 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' error when I run it.

Update: I edited my code to fix maximum recursion depth but now I am getting a different AttributeError.

The following is my updated code:

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
        
    def insert(self, key, value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = BSTNode(key, value)
        elif key < self.root.key:
            if self.root.left is None:
                self.root.left = BSTNode(key, value)
            else:
                self.root.left.insert(key, value)
        elif key > self.root.key:
            if self.root.right is None:
                self.root.right = BSTNode(key, value)
            else:
                self.root.right.insert(key, value)
                
        return self.root
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    T = BST()
    T.insert(5, 'Mujeeb')
    T.insert(4, 'Hamza')
    T.insert(7, 'Ayesha')
    T.insert(9, 'Mahnoor')
    T.insert(11, 'Ali')
    print(T.root.right.key)
```

The error I was getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-1eef6d5c8be5> in <module>
     23     T = BST()
     24     T.insert(5, 'Mujeeb')
---> 25     T.insert(4, 'Hamza')
     26     T.insert(7, 'Ayesha')
     27 

<ipython-input-29-1eef6d5c8be5> in insert(self, key, value)
     15             self.root = BSTNode(key, value)
     16         elif key < self.root.key:
---> 17             self.root.left = self.insert(key, value)
     18         elif key > self.root.key:
     19             self.root.right = self.insert(key, value)

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-29-1eef6d5c8be5> in insert(self, key, value)
     15             self.root = BSTNode(key, value)
     16         elif key < self.root.key:
---> 17             self.root.left = self.insert(key, value)
     18         elif key > self.root.key:
     19             self.root.right = self.insert(key, value)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

The new error I get with the updated code:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-8ebfd3bbaceb> in <module>
     30 if __name__ == '__main__':
     31     T = BST()
---> 32     T.insert(5, 'Mujeeb')
     33     T.insert(4, 'Hamza')
     34     T.insert(7, 'Ayesha')

<ipython-input-23-8ebfd3bbaceb> in insert(self, key, value)
     14         if self.root is None:
     15             self.root = BSTNode(key, value)
---> 16             self.root.insert(key, value)
     17         elif key < self.root.key:
     18             if self.root.left is None:

AttributeError: 'BSTNode' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

I would be grateful if you could provide any indicators to where I am going wrong with this, thank you.

Comment: You call `self.insert` infinitely. Call `insert` on the right or left node.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? If I call insert on right or left node, it throws the error that Nonetype object has no attribute insert

Comment: You seem to know how to handle the case when `root == None`; apply that logic to these branches...

Comment: @ScottHunter Understood!

Comment: @ScottHunter After extending that logic to both conditions, I get a different error that BSTNode has no attribute insert...

Comment: You didn't call `insert` when `root == None`.

Comment: @ScottHunter but aren't I already creating and inserting a new node when root == None and setting it as the root

Comment: Creating the node & assigning it *is* inserting it (if you assign it to where it should go, which isn't `root`).

Comment: It would be good if you would give feed-back on the answer below. Did it not answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "insert" node always operate on the root node of the tree.
It should operate on whatever node it is inserting.

Maybe it is easier if you use a single class instead of a class for a Node and another for a Tree, that way, each node will have its own "insert" method that will do the right thing.

```
class BSTNode:
    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        
    def insert(self, key, value):
        
        if key <= self.key:
            if not self.left:
                self.left = BSTNode(key, value)
            else:
                self.left.insert(key, value)
        elif key > self.key:
            if not self.right:
                self.right = BSTNode(key, value)
            else:
                self.right.insert(key, value)
```

Comment: This gave me a good idea of where I was going wrong. I created another private method as _insert that took the curr_node as one of the parameters and then used this method recursively in the normal insert method with self.root set to curr_node there. I did this because I wanted separate classes for BSTNode and BST